# Transparent Local Notification / Callback

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm struggling with what's probably a basic iOS concept.

My apps needs to set an alarm for a specific time (10 mins in the future, 30 mins in the future, etc). I need to execute a line of code (and access a sharedInstance in my app), when that delay expires.

Local Notifications sound like the right tool, but I do NOT want to notify the user. I understand there's a callback feature, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do what I want. It almost seems like abuse.

Any comments? How do you schedule a block of code to be run, in the future?

Edit: I need background support, or at the very least I need this to work when the screen is off.

Comment: Look at [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003747)

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I need this to work when the screen is off (I can't reasonably expect the user to have the app open after 30mins).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot accomplish this locally. You need to look at remote notifications. Remote notifications are silent push notifications which give your app time to run in the background. This solution will only work on iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

Local notifications should be used specifically for notifying the user of something (when the app is in the background).

When your app is running you should use an `NSTimer` to schedule future execution.

An alternative if you love GCD and blocks would be to use `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, #TIME# * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{...`

---

If you're playing music then you get an opportunity to run in between each song (or is it when the buffer empties, I can't remember) and you can stop playback at that time. If you store an `NSDate` of the time that you should turn off then you can check against it each time you get to run.

Comment: The user needs to trigger a notification for your app to run from the background. You can only run in the background after an arbitrary time by cheating (your app would get rejected from the store).

Comment: That sucks. Will an NSTimer run when the screen is off (but the app still open)?

Comment: The app is still inactive when the screen is off so it should be saving power and nothing happening. Users aren't happy when they find they have no battery because an app has sucked all the power up while 'not being used'.

Comment: I'm making a sleep-timer type of app. We'll play music for the time specified. Users will expect some BG operation; will Apple reject the app for this?